# Mass NPM 3.5.1 warnings - unsure why all of a sudden

Tags: meteor, npm, webpack

Without knowingly changing anything, all of a sudden today I started getting a huge amount of warnings related to NPM 3.5.1 every time I build. Anyone have any idea why or how I can get rid of or suppress them?

If it matters, it's happening launching a Meteor app (via the Meteor command) built using webpack...

************UPDATE: 12/10/15****************
OK, I figured out what is going on now, but not quite sure how to 'fix' it. The system (which BTW is Windows 10) has NPM 3.51 installed by the project has a symlink to the node_modules directory so cannot be updated there.

Does anyone know how to get around this? I tried going into the directory and running update from there and that fails too. Is there a way to remove a symlink in Windows, do the update, then put it back?

Any help is more than appreciated because there are literally hundreds of warnings and and I can't see the relevant console output (or scroll back up to it because it's out of the display buffer). This is really hindering my progress.

TIA!

```
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of lodash.repeat with lodash.rep
eat@3.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of lodash._basetostring with lod
ash._basetostring@3.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of lodash.repeat with lodash.rep
eat@3.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of lodash._basetostring with lod
ash._basetostring@3.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of lodash.repeat with lodash.rep
eat@3.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of once with once@1.3.2
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of opener with opener@1.4.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of os-homedir with os-homedir@1.
0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of os-tmpdir with os-tmpdir@1.0.
1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of path-is-inside with path-is-i
nside@1.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of mute-stream with mute-stream@
0.0.5
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of read-cmd-shim with read-cmd-s
him@1.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of util-extend with util-extend@
1.0.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of jju with jju@1.2.1
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of read-package-tree with read-p
ackage-tree@5.1.2
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of readdir-scoped-modules with r
eaddir-scoped-modules@1.0.2
npm WARN In npm@3.5.1 replacing bundled version of realize-package-specifier with...
```